# Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9042: bind: address already in use'

Tags: cassandra, apache-kafka, docker-compose, pipeline

I am trying to setup landoop/fast-data-dev cluster for kafka connector and cassandra cluster with 3 instance but I am getting "Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9042: bind: address already in use'".

With `sudo netstat -pna | grep 9042`
I am getting:
`tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1166/java`

I tried 
`pkill -f CassandraDaemon` and
`docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`
with no success.
Here is the docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:

        kafka-cluseter:
                image: landoop/fast-data-dev:latest
                environment:
                        ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1
                        RUNTESTS: 0
                ports:
                        - 2181:2181
                        - 3030:3030
                        - 8081-8083:8081-8083
                        - 9581-9585:9581-9585
                        - 9092:9092
        ###############################
        cassandra0:
                image: cassandra:latest
                container_name: cassandra0
                ports:
                        - 9042:9042
                        - 7199:7199

        ###############################
        cassandra1:
                image: cassandra:latest
                container_name: cassandra1
                ports:
                        - 9142:9042
                links:
                        - cassandra0:seed
                environment:
                        - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=seed

        ###############################
        cassandra2:
                image: cassandra:latest
                container_name: cassandra2
                ports:
                        - 9242:9042
                links:
                        - cassandra0:seed
                environment:
                        - CASSANDRA_SEEDS=seed
```

Cassandra instances are not up when 
 `sudo docker-compose up -d`

```
Creating network "kafka-code_default" with the default driver
Creating cassandra0                  ... error
Creating kafka-code_kafka-cluseter_1 ... 

ERROR: for cassandra0  Cannot start service cassandra0: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cassandra0 (e5383709e9e9b45bbdf57a6445da0df4e4aa228269ad1d18c4c3de70bc903b0a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0Creating kafka-code_kafka-cluseter_1 ... done

ERROR: for cassandra0  Cannot start service cassandra0: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint cassandra0 (e5383709e9e9b45bbdf57a6445da0df4e4aa228269ad1d18c4c3de70bc903b0a): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:9042: bind: address already in use'
```

Comment: run `sudo fuser -n tcp -k 9042`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got something else running on port 9042, as you showed:

```
sudo netstat -pna | grep 9042

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9042          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1166/java
```

This is why you can't start the Docker container which is also wanting to use the same port.

The problem is that you've assumed that it must be Docker or Cassandra on that port  and tried to kill them

```
pkill -f CassandraDaemon
docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)
```

What you actually need to do is find out what process `1166` is, and kill that - or if it should be running, pick a different port for your Docker container to use

```
ps -ef|grep 1166
```